# scrollTop going back top before scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which scrolls the page to a given offset. I'm using the parallax effect, so all my elements (and pages, or "slides") are positioned depending on the scroll bar location.

My little problem is that when I click a link to another slide, it scrolls the page to the desired offset, but the event binded is triggered. Which should be OK, to keep the smooth effect. But there's a little glitch, it seems that the `scrollTop` function goes back to top for a millisecond before executing correctly. So it lookes like theres another page displaying for a millisecond every time I click on a link before scrolling to the right place.

Here is my code:

```
    for(var i=1;i<8;i++)
    {
        (function(slideNum) {
            var tempName = 'slide'+slideNum;
            //console.log(defaultPositions["slide"+i].top);
            $('a.slide'+i).bind('click', function() {
                $.scrollTo((defaultPositions[tempName].top/slidesScrollSpeed)+1+'px', 800);
            });
        })(i);
    }
```

I know it might be hard to find the problem in this code, but it's all I could find that is related to that. Do you know what's wrong?

Thanks!

PS: `scrollTo` is a jQuery plugin but has the same glitch as `scrollTop`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to prevent the default action of the links.  I'm assuming you have something like `href="#"` on your links?  Change your click binding to:

```
$('a.slide'+slideNum).bind('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.scrollTo((defaultPositions[tempName].top/slidesScrollSpeed)+1+'px', 800);
});
```

Edit: I noticed you pass in `i` as `slideNum` but then use `i`, so I changed my code to use the passed in value stored in `slideNum`

Comment: Wow it works, thank you very much, that was it! I completely forgot about default actions.